# Address book location in Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

How can I find the location of Address book of Mozilla Thunderbird in windows 7.I also want to know the name of that file in which Thunderbird stores its contacts detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try browsing `%AppData%\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\xxxxxxx\abook.mab` File

```
xxxxxxx could be any random string for your profile
```

> ThunderBird 38.5.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have found that file but there is another file with same file format named as history.mab. can you explain me both are similar or hold same data?